# how to set Start Date later than End Date for dojo datetextbox

Tags: dojo

I have these two start and end datetextbox. If I select start date of any date then end date should be later than start date.please help

Comment: After lots of effort.I solved the problem by below code.

coverageStartDate = function(startDateId, endDateId) {
     var startDate = dojo.byId(startDateId).value;
     var startDateArray = startDate.split("/");
     var formattedStartDate = startDateArray[2] + "-" + startDateArray[0] + "-" + startDateArray[1];
     var endDateObj = dijit.byId(endDateId);
     endDateObj.constraints.min = formattedStartDate;
    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_DateTextBox.html). The "Date pairs" example to be precise.